# C++ - dealing with infinitesimal numbers

Tags: c++, c

I need to find some way to deal with infinitesimial double values.
For example:

exp(**-0.00000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000003**)= **0.99999999999999999999999999999899999999999999999997**

But exp function produce result = **1.000000000000000000000000000000**

So my first thought was to make my own exp function. Unfortunately I am getting same output.

```
double my_exp(double x)
{
    bool minus = x < 0;
    x = abs(x);
    double exp = (double)1 + x;
    double temp = x;
    for (int i = 2; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        temp *= x / (double)i;
        exp = exp + temp;
    }
    return minus ? exp : (double)1 / exp;
}
```

I found that issue is when such small numbers like 1.00000000000000000003e-030 doesn't work well when we try to subtract it, neither both if we subtracting or adding such a small number the result always is equal to 1.

Have U any idea how to manage with this?

Comment: Smells like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please describe Why you need this? What problem this should solve. Now your question is a bit strange and detached from important context. It is possible that answer provided fits your needs, but also it is possible you are doing something in wrong way with some very simple topic.

Comment: The format commonly used for `double` represents numbers as a sign and a 53-bit significand scaling by a power of two. When it is representing a number just under one, the scaling means the highest bit of the significand represents 2^−1, so the lowest bit represents 2^−53. 0.00000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000003 is around 2^−100. So the `double` format cannot possibly represent 1 minus that value; the result has to be rounded to 1. All your calculations after that are useless. If you are going to work with floating-point, you must learn the basics of floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: Potential solutions for this depend on what work you need to do. For evaluating certain formulas, the `expm1` function is sufficient, because the function it provides, e^x−1, can provide an accurate result for small values of x whereas `exp(x)−1` cannot. But whether that suffices for your needs or you would need extended-precision software or some other solution depends on the work you need to do. So you must update the question with more information.

Comment: You should try using *fixed point* notation and arithmetic.  Basically, you're changing the units of the numeric data.  For example, with $US, you would use pennies (1/100) instead of dollars to get more precision.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: How does that have anything to do with this question? The calculation they are doing involves a value differing from 1 by around 2^−100. Fixed-point arithmetic does not magically give you that much more precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using std::expm1

> Computes the e (Euler's number, 2.7182818) raised to the given power
> arg, minus 1.0. This function is more accurate than the expression
> std::exp(arg)-1.0 if arg is close to zero.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "expm1(-0.00000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000003) = " << std::expm1(-0.00000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000003) << '\n';
}
```

Run the example in the below source by changing the arguments to your very small numbers.

Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/expm1

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way of dealing with such small numbers is to use existing libraries. You could try [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) starting with their [example to calculate billions of digits of pi](https://gmplib.org/pi-with-gmp). Another library, [MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org/) which is based on GMP, seems to be a good choice. I don't know when to choose one over the other.